# Override VirtualizationMode default value on TreeViewItems

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, ui-virtualization

I want the default value of `VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode` to `Recycling`, mainly on `TreeViewItems`. It may be something simple I'm missing but I've tried all these:

```
<TreeView VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Pixel"
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling" />
</Style>
```

```
static MainWindow()
{
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationModeProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(VirtualizingPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(VirtualizationMode.Recycling));
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationModeProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(VirtualizationMode.Recycling));
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationModeProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(TreeViewItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(VirtualizationMode.Recycling));
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationModeProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(VirtualizingStackPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(VirtualizationMode.Recycling));
}
```

But it all seems to do nothing. According to the Xaml live property explorer.
[image]

How to reproduce:

- Download and run the source code from [github](https://github.com/StllUnknwn/TreeViewVirtualization) in Visual Studio in debug mode.
- Open the "Live Visual Tree" window in Visual Studio and find a `VirtualizingStackPanel` under some `TreeViewItem`.
- Right-click, select properties, and find the `VirualizationMode` property.

Comment: Are you not binding itemssource on the treeview? If you set it directly or add items in xaml/code then I don't think it can virtualize.

Comment: ItemsSource is bound, I just removed that from the code snippet.

Comment: Please update your question to show how someone would reproduce your issue.

Comment: I did. You can get my code from github, it's a fairly simple app just to reproduce this issue. Please ask for more specific info if missing.

Comment: @HosseinEbrahimi: Setting the `VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode` attached property of the `TreeView` is good enough. If you look at a `TreeViewItem`, you should note that it has a `VirtualizationMode` of `Recycling` at runtime.  What is your issue?

Comment: @mm8 The snapshot in my question is taken from the `VirtualizingStackPanel` under a `TreeViewItem`. It shows that `VirtualizationMode` is still `Standard`.

Comment: It's unclear from where and how the snapshot in your question is taken. How to reproduce?